# Last child / last of type not working on div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to change the last `div`'s color. Neither `last-child` and `last-of-type` work. My code:

```css
.blue-back {
  background-color:blue;
}

.blue-back:last-of-type {
  background-color:red;
}

.blue-back:last-child {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="blue-back">
          <p class="mb-0 text-center text-white">Fase</p>
          <p style="font-size:29px; font-weight:600;" class="mb-0 text-center text-white font-weight-600">1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="blue-back">
          <p class="mb-0 text-center text-white">Fase</p>
          <p style="font-size:29px; font-weight:600;" class="mb-0 text-center text-white font-weight-600">1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="blue-back">
          <p class="mb-0 text-center text-white">Fase</p>
          <p style="font-size:29px; font-weight:600;" class="mb-0 text-center text-white font-weight-600">1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You just need to make sure there are actually children within in a parent. In this case there is only one last-child called .blue-black per item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the last child of `.blue-back` is always the current item. You need to do:

```css
.col-md-4:last-child .blue-back {
    background-color:red;
}
```

See a CodePen demo here: https://codepen.io/ryan_pixelers/pen/KKKXBaz

Comment: Have you tried this and found it works?

Comment: I know it works

Comment: Hi, i tried this and everything is still blue. nothing changes to red @RyanMc

Comment: Definitely does work https://codepen.io/ryan_pixelers/pen/KKKXBaz are you typing class names wrong @Gago ?

Comment: Yes u right it works. Thanks man. @RyanMc

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `:last-child` selector to .col-md-4 children of .row parent.

So you can use:

```
.row .col-md-4:last-child .blue-back {
  background-color: red;
}
```

or

```
.row > div:last-child .blue-back {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```css
.blue-back {
  background-color: blue;
}

.row .col-md-4:last-child .blue-back {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="blue-back">
          <p class="mb-0 text-center text-white">Fase</p>
          <p style="font-size:29px; font-weight:600;" class="mb-0 text-center text-white font-weight-600">1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="blue-back">
          <p class="mb-0 text-center text-white">Fase</p>
          <p style="font-size:29px; font-weight:600;" class="mb-0 text-center text-white font-weight-600">1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="blue-back">
          <p class="mb-0 text-center text-white">Fase</p>
          <p style="font-size:29px; font-weight:600;" class="mb-0 text-center text-white font-weight-600">1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```